# Get name of network that a network interface is connected to

Tags: c#, .net, networking, interface

In Windows Control Panel, you can find a list of network interfaces/connections which displays the following:

[image: network interfaces]

In the .NET framework these are represented in the `NetworkInterface` class (and found via `NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces`).

For reference, say I'm reading properties from the Ethernet interface - the `NetworkInterface.Name` property returns `"Ethernet"`, the `NetworkInterface.Description` property returns `"Realtek PCIe FE Family Controller"`.

However, nothing in the class seems to be able to get me the name of the network it's connected to (in this case `"BELL024"`). How would I go about getting that string? I have to know what network the interface is associated with, not just a list of the networks that exist.

Comment: Networks do not have names, they have network addresses. There may a DNS name for the network on a DNS server, but that is not inherent in the network, and a DNS server could have multiple names for a network, or different DNS servers could have different names for the network. What a host calls a network is fairly arbitrary. A user could rename a Wi-Fi network to say Ethernet, or vice versa.

Comment: I see. How did Windows/this host determine the string "BELL024" for the network? It doesn't matter for me if the user can rename it, I only want it to be displayed alongside the network interface name so they can easily tell what network the app will be directing traffic to.

Comment: That is something that someone entered in Windows. It may be the Windows workgroup that Windows discovered. If it is a workgroup name, it could exist on multiple interfaces.

Comment: It seems like what I'm looking for is the SSID that the router/modem is using. I could be wrong but I'll look into it some more.

Comment: That is a possibility. That would only be on a Wi-Fi network. There is no such concept on ethernet. You may also be able to see multiple SSIDs on Wi-Fi, and the SSID can change on that interface if a new association is made.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It turns out information about each network is stored as a 'network profile' by Windows, storing it's name and other info like whether it's public or not. The name can be changed by users in the control panel, but in my situation that's not a problem.

The **Windows API Code Pack** from Microsoft contains the APIs necessary to get the collection of network profiles. As it contains a lot of bloat that I don't need, the bare minimum code to wrap the Windows API [can be found here](https://github.com/sawch/Windows-API-Network-List-Manager).

A collection of the network profiles can then be found like so:

```
//Get the networks that are currently connected to
var networks = NetworkListManager.GetNetworks(NetworkConnectivityLevels.Connected);
```

Each object in the collection represents a network profile and contains a collection of `NetworkConnection` objects. Each `NetworkConnection` object appears to be info about an interface's connection to the base network.

```
foreach(Network network in networks)
{
    //Name property corresponds to the name I originally asked about
    Console.WriteLine("[" + network.Name + "]");

    Console.WriteLine("\t[NetworkConnections]");
    foreach(NetworkConnection conn in network.Connections)
    {
        //Print network interface's GUID
        Console.WriteLine("\t\t" + conn.AdapterId.ToString());
    }
}
```

The `NetworkConnection.AdapterId` property is the same network interface GUID that the `NetworkInterface.Id` property knows.

So, you can determine what network an interface is connected to, by checking if one of the network's connections have the same ID as the interface. Note that they're represented differently, so you'll have to do a bit more work:

[image: example image]

Both my Wi-Fi and Ethernet interfaces are connected to the BELL024 network in the above example.

Comment: Hint: Guid.Parse to easily convert `NetworkInterface.Id` string to the same type as NetworkConnection.AdapterId, then Guid.Equals(...)

Answer (score 2):

You can use WMI to query for your network name. You can use this code as a sample:

```
ManagementScope oMs = new ManagementScope();  
ObjectQuery oQuery =  
    new ObjectQuery("Select * From Win32_NetworkAdapter");  
ManagementObjectSearcher oSearcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(oMs, oQuery);  
ManagementObjectCollection oReturnCollection = oSearcher.Get();  
foreach (ManagementObject oReturn in oReturnCollection) 
{
    if (oReturn.Properties["NetConnectionID"].Value != null)  
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Name : " + oReturn.Properties["NetConnectionID"].Value);
        }
}
```

Comment: That only seems to return the name of the network interface (the same as `NetworkInterface.Name` property). I looped through all of the possible properties that method has and none of them provide the name of the network I'm looking for unfortunately.

Comment: If you are looking for a C# equivalent of PowerShell command `Get-NetAdapter`, then this is your answer.

Answer (score 2):

On Windows 8 and Windows 2012 and higher you can query WMI class **MSFT_NetConnectionProfile** from **root/StandardCimv2** namespace.

It shouldn't be too hard to convert this to C#.

```
Get-WmiObject -Namespace root/StandardCimv2 -Class MSFT_NetConnectionProfile | Format-Table InterfaceAlias, Name
```